# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /home/public_html/index.php on line 2

Tags: php, mysqli

The following error occurs when using the PHP script below:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in /home/public_html/index.php on line 2

```
<?
while($Recents = mysqli_fetch_object($RecentForums)){
    if($Recents == 0){
    echo"
        <center>
            No recent forum posts!
        </center>
        ";
    }
else{
    $getPoster = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID='".$Recents->PosterID."'");
    $gP = mysqli_fetch_object($getPoster);
    echo"
    <img src='http://sitelink.com/Images/BulletPointArrow.png'>
    &nbsp;
    <a href='http://sitelink.com/forum/ShowPost.php?ID=".$Recents->ID."'>
    ".$Recents->Title."
    </a>
    <br />
    <font style='font-size:11px'>
    by 
    <a href='http://http://sitelink.com/user.php?ID=".$gP->ID."' style='font-size:11px;'>
    ".$gP->Username."
    </a>
    on ".$Recents->TimePosted."
    </font>
    <div style='margin-top:7px;'></div>
    ";
    }
    }?>
```

Comment: show us what `var_dump($Recents);` is showing? Also `$Recents` is an object so you cannot compare it directly with some integer value like `0`.

Comment: @Wizar45d - show us what it contains (e.g.  what `var_dump($Recents);` is showing) as you were asked. Then we'll be able to tell you

Comment: You 're literally using `mysqli_fetch_OBJECT` (hint: ***object***) and then you instantly compare it to `0` (which wouldn't be an object, it would be an int). What are you trying to do? Did you mean `if(empty($Recents))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if no results were found you need to use `mysqli_num_rows()`:

```
if( mysqli_num_rows($RecentForums) == 0 ) {
    echo "
        <center>
            No recent forum posts!
        </center>";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, If you need to display the results - you can do something like:

```
$recordsFound = false;
while( $Recents = mysqli_fetch_object($RecentForums) ){
    $recordsFound = true;
    echo $Recents->Title . "\n";
}

if( !$recordsFound ) {
    echo "<center>
        No recent forum posts!
    </center>";
}
```

Comment: Should I remove the `while($Recents = mysqli_fetch_object($RecentForums)){`?

Comment: Yes, unless you want to loop the data returned from the query - Then you need to check  `if($Recents->myCoulomNameInTable == 0){`

Comment: Does that go above `if( mysqli_num_rows($RecentForums) == 0 ) {`?

Comment: Are you interested in the results returned from the query, or are you just want the check if any records were found?

Comment: The script checks if there were any new posts. If there isn't it displays 'No recent forum posts'. If there is recent forum posts though, it displays the title of the post and when it was posted.

Comment: @Wizar45d So start by checking `num_rows` and if it's more than 0 you can loop through `fetch_object` to get your values.